# Path-connectedness of singletons (question about Munkres)

Tags: algebraic-topology

In corollary 59.2, Munkres states:

Suppose $X = U \cup V$, where U and V are open sets of X; suppose $U \cap V$ is nonempty and path connected. If U and V are simply connected, then X is simply connected.

Then comes exercise one. As a note, Munkres states that the union of two simply connected spaces having a point in common is not necessarily simply connected. The exercise is about two copies of $S^2$ having a point in common.

Since the spheres have a point in common, the intersection is nonempty. Then why does the corollary 59.2 not apply? In the definition of path connectedness, do the points x and y joined by a path have to be distinct from each other? The definition in Munkres is a little ambiguous in this regard.

Comment: The problem is not path-connectedness, it's openness.

Comment: Think about where $U$ is the closed left-half of a circle and $V$ is the closed right-half of a circle.  Then $U\cup V$ is a circle, which is not simply connected, but $U\cap V$ consists of two points which are not path connected.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yeah, that's because that's two points. The sphere's in the exercise are connected at just one point. That's different.

Comment: Note that the wedge-sum of two $S^2$ _is_ simply connected. You can apply corollary 59.2 if you choose slightly different subspaces, you need to include a small open part of the other sphere. With the subspaces being the spheres themselves, you have closed but not open subspaces. (And the compactness of the spheres shows they are closed, since the wedge-sum is Hausdorff.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the non-applicability of the corollary is due to the fact that the individual spheres are not open in the wedge sum.

Remember that the wedge sum is formed as a quotient of the disjoint union of the two spheres, and so has the quotient topology. So to see that an individual sphere is not open, you can note that its preimage in the disjoint union (which is the disjoint union of a sphere and a point) is not open. By a similar analysis though, you can see that each sphere is closed in the wedge product.

Furthermore, as also suggested in the comments, you can choose slightly different sets $U$ and $V$ that allow you to apply the corollary. Let $U$ be one of the spheres union an open neighbourhood (in the other sphere) of the intersection point, and let $V$ be analogously defined using the other sphere. Then the intersection is a cone which is contractible, hence in particular connected and simply connected, and $U$ and $V$ each clearly deformation retract onto spheres hence are simply connected. Applying the corollary at his stage completes the proof.

Addendum: In the language of fundamental groups (which give you some measure of how far a space is from being simply connected), this phenomenon is a consequence of Van Kampen's theorem (applied to spaces with 'nice' local topology) which tells you that the fundamental group of a wedge-sum is the free product of the fundamental groups of the original spaces.